# When I try to go to a URL directly in production mode, React displays an Error 404 page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am currently using React 16.10.2, react-router-dom 5.1.2, and I have my router configured to various routes and to display a custom Error 404 page when no path is specified.

When I use my application in development mode, it runs fine. When I use it in production mode via `npm run build` and `serve -s build`, it loads the base URL at `localhost:8443` correctly, but when I login or try to go to a route manually using a URL directly, it displays an '404 page not found' message.

I have read online that I should place an .htaccess file in my /public folder or try to add a `basename` to my `BrowserRouter` but neither have worked. I know that some of the routing in this application is taking place by directly manipulating `window.location.href`. How can I preserve this functionality while still redirecting to the correct page?

This application was made with `create-react-app`. Here is my App.js:

```
...
if (authenticated) {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/membership'>
                        <SafetyArea/>
                        <Sidebar/>
                        <Membership></Membership>
                        <SafetyArea/>
                        <Footer/>
                    </Route>

                    <Route path='/payment'>
                        <SafetyArea/>
                        <Sidebar/>
                        <Payment></Payment>
                        <Footer/>
                    </Route>

                    <Route path='/success'>
                        <SafetyArea/>
                        <Sidebar/>
                        <Success></Success>
                        <SafetyArea/>
                        <Footer/>
                    </Route>
...

                    <Route>
                        <SafetyArea/>
                        <Error404/>
                    </Route>


                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
```

Here is my .htaccess file (so far I haven't seen its effect):

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Comment: do you have _redirects file inside public folder? Are you using react-router?

Comment: How is it being hosted (Apache, heroku, etc.) ?

Comment: can you provide a sample of your code so i can help you better ?

Comment: Right now it's not being hosted. We would like to stage it via Gitlab CI, but right now I'm just trying to get a production build on my local machine so that I can demo a version of my application that doesn't display all the development error messages.